# How to aggregate the number of indexes on a table and columns per index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a simple query that returns every table, index and the columns of the index in a database. I'd like to add two aggregate columns that return the number of indexes on a table and then the amount of columns on each index.

I'm looking to build a report of every database on a server, each table in there and each index and column to look for tables with too many indexes and large indexes with more than 2-3 key columns.

```
 SELECT 
 @@SERVERNAME as server_name
,DB_NAME() as database_name
 ,TableName = t.name
 ,IndexName = ind.name
 ,ColumnName = col.name
 ,ic.key_ordinal
 ,ind.is_disabled
 ,IndexId = ind.index_id
 ,ColumnId = ic.index_column_id
 FROM 
 sys.indexes ind 
 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and 
 ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
  INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and 
  ic.column_id = col.column_id 
  INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
  WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 
  ORDER BY database_name, t.name, ind.name, ind.index_id
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a stable, reliable, and free script, try `sp_BlitzIndex`. As a disclaimer, it's part of an [open source project](http://firstresponderkit.org) I contribute to.

If you run it like so, it will go through all the databases on your server and produce the information you asked for, plus a lot of other nice details.

`EXEC sp_BlitzIndex @GetAllDatabases = 1, @Mode = 2;`

Answer (score 2):

**Something like this?**

```
 SELECT 
 @@SERVERNAME as server_name
,DB_NAME() as database_name
 ,TableName = t.name
 ,IndexName = ind.name
 ,IndexId = ind.index_id
 ,sum(case when key_ordinal = 0 then 0 else 1 end ) as amount_of_key_columns
 , count(ind.name) over(partition by t.name) as indexes_on_table
 FROM 
 sys.indexes ind 
 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and 
 ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
  INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and 
  ic.column_id = col.column_id 
  INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
  WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    group by t.name,ind.name, ind.index_id
```

**Example of a Resultset: (one record for each index)**

```
server_name database_name   TableName   IndexName   IndexId amount_of_key_columns   indexes_on_table
SRVSQLA1      my_test      tabela1     AKF_tabela1_Kod  3          1    3
SRVSQLA1      my_test      tabela1     BK_tabela1       1          1    3
SRVSQLA1      my_test      tabela1     PK_tabela1       2          1    3
```

**To do it for all the databases in a server:**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE C CURSOR for SELECT NAME FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 and state = 0;
DECLARE @dbname NVARCHAR(255);
OPEN C 
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @dbname;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @sql = '

USE '+QUOTENAME(@dbname)+'

 SELECT 
 @@SERVERNAME as server_name
 ,'''+QUOTENAME(@dbname)+''' as database_name
 ,TableName = t.name
 ,IndexName = ind.name
 ,IndexId = ind.index_id
 ,sum(case when key_ordinal = 0 then 0 else 1 end ) as amount_of_key_columns
 , count(ind.name) over(partition by t.name) as indexes_on_table
 FROM 
 sys.indexes ind 
 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic
 ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id 
 and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
 INNER JOIN sys.columns col 
 ON ic.object_id = col.object_id 
 and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
 INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
 ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
 WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 
 GROUP by t.name,ind.name, ind.index_id;';

EXEC(@sql);
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbname;
END
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Comment: Thx, only issue i'm having is that it counts the rows where the key_ordinal is 0. Playing with it to get around it. Worst case I might create a CTE for this part.

Comment: Ow yeah i made a mistake, now only the key columns should be counted